# What are common writing tropes in dark romance?

Tags: creative-writing, genre, romance, tropes

What are common writing tropes in dark romance? What do readers expect from a dark romance?

For those of you who don’t know what “dark romance” is, here is a list of examples https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/dark-romance

A famous book I can think of closest to the genre would be Fifty Shades of Grey (if you take out most of the sex scenes).

Comment: Hi Klara! This is a pretty broad question; it'll be hard to answer in Q&A format. Is there maybe a particular issue you're trying to solve; something you're uncertain about, that makes you ask this?

Comment: I want to know what I need to have in a dark romance novel so as to not disappoint readers. Like, what do they expect a dark romance to have?

Comment: I have been encouraged to phrase these types of questions the way I have. I’ve posted a similar question before.

Comment: I think this is too broad. I suggest you re-read a favorite dark romance with an analytic mindset (don't get lost in the story). See if you can generalize the types of peril characters are in, what makes characters both "dark" and seductive, and generalize the type and extent of hidden secrets. Generalize the basic transformation of the main characters: Is it innocence to horror, or innocence to darkness, or not-so-innocent to something else?  Try to see, over a few of YOUR favorites, what commonalities exist between the stories. Those are the tropes you seek, the ones that seduce YOU.

Comment: For example, in romances, people tell me I gotta have happy endings otherwise I risk getting one-star reviews (romance without happy endings is a love story, not a romance). Are there any rules like that that apply to dark romance specifically?

Comment: This question is similar to https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/31361/what-are-most-common-tropes-of-a-paranormal-book-and-dark-fantasy-book so I suggest to leave it open, but I suggest @KlaraRaškaj to edit it and be more specific, so that the question does not result too broad. For instance what do you mean with "dark romance"? What examples of novels of that genre can you make? etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are at least two types of dark romance - The contemporary (http://heatherknight.net/what-is-dark-romance/) and the Victorian Gothic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_romanticism) version. Which? The very least you need is a heroine in the clutches of a dark hero, and ending well is entirely optional.

Comment: I’ve seen some blog posts online not specifying a subgenre of dark romance, but talking about “dark romance” in general. I’ve read that it needs some darker and more disturbing elements, such as abuse, kidnapping, and such—a not so nice guy love interest—and it needs to have a happy ending. I just wanted to make sure it was true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heather Knight covers it here briefly.

http://heatherknight.net/what-is-dark-romance/

It lists some of the basic fundamentals of dark romance.

And. . . .

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DestructiveRomance

The latter could be applied to nearly any genre, I figure.

Comment: Thank you :D I haven’t come across that one! Really helpful!